# Kubernetes PodPreset not working

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to play with [PodPreset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/) Kubernetes feature on my test cluster running version 1.6.6. Kube-apiserver is started with (included just the relevant part):

```html
--storage-backend=etcd2 
--admission-control ...,PodPreset 
--runtime-config=settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset
```

However I still get:

```html
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.701156   22088 reflector.go:236] Listing and watching *settings.PodPreset from k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:70
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.701487   22088 round_trippers.go:398] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf, */*" -H "User-Agent: kube-apiserver/v1.6.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/7fa1c17" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX” https://A.B.C.D:443/apis/settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpresets?resourceVersion=0
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.702702   22088 wrap.go:75] GET /apis/settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpresets?resourceVersion=0: (266.839µs) 404 [[kube-apiserver/v1.6.6 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/7fa1c17] A.B.C.D:37122]
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703446   22088 round_trippers.go:417] GET https://A.B.C.D:443/apis/settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpresets?resourceVersion=0 404 Not Found in 1 milliseconds
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703483   22088 round_trippers.go:423] Response Headers:
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703502   22088 round_trippers.go:426]     Content-Type: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703515   22088 round_trippers.go:426]     Content-Length: 112
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703527   22088 round_trippers.go:426]     Date: Tue, 27 Jun 2017 14:34:25 GMT
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: I0627 16:34:25.703606   22088 request.go:989] Response Body:
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000000  6b 38 73 00 0a 0c 0a 02  76 31 12 06 53 74 61 74  |k8s.....v1..Stat|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000010  75 73 12 58 0a 04 0a 00  12 00 12 07 46 61 69 6c  |us.X........Fail|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000020  75 72 65 1a 30 74 68 65  20 73 65 72 76 65 72 20  |ure.0the server |
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000030  63 6f 75 6c 64 20 6e 6f  74 20 66 69 6e 64 20 74  |could not find t|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000040  68 65 20 72 65 71 75 65  73 74 65 64 20 72 65 73  |he requested res|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000050  6f 75 72 63 65 22 08 4e  6f 74 46 6f 75 6e 64 2a  |ource".NotFound*|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: 00000060  08 0a 00 12 00 1a 00 28  00 30 94 03 1a 00 22 00  |.......(.0....".|
Jun 27 16:34:25 host kube-apiserver[22088]: E0627 16:34:25.703783   22088 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:70: Failed to list *settings.PodPreset: the server could not find the requested resource
```

And obviously when I try to submit my resource through kubectl it fails.

```html
error: error validating "pod-preset.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field resources for v1alpha1.PodPresetSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Cluster itself is running normally (I have multiple services and pods). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1" API endpoint is enabled by default in 1.6.x. So you don't need to specify in runtime-config parameter.

Can you try without specifying anything in "runtime-config" parameter. You just need PodPreset in admission-control, which you have already.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps offtopic: but where is the list what I am exactly able to enable through runtime-config and what is already on by default in what version? I tried without "runtime-config" and now API server looks ok. I upgraded kubectl to 1.6.6 and it still fails unless I add --validate=false. How do you list pod presets then without going directly through etcdctl?

Comment: Just FYI: with kubectl 1.7 "pod preset" resource finally works like you are used to from others.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
minikube stop

minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.runtime-config=settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true
```

Now retry playing with podpreset. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you share your system information?

I'm using `ubuntu 20.04` , minikube `v1.24.0` , kubernetes `v1.22.3` . I can `minikube start` success, but failed with `extra-config`.
Error output told likely: `The kubelet is not running`