# Pod presets not working on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm trying to test out pod presets on minikube.  I run the following command to start minikube:

> minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch *switch name* --extra-config=apiserver.admission-control="NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota,PodPreset"

Once the cluster starts up, I run `kubectl get podpreset`, which gives me back `the server doesn't have a resource type 'podpreset'`.  I was under the impression that I just had to add PodPreset to admission control and then pod presets would work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Some additional info:

```
OS: Windows 10

minikube version: v0.28.0

kubectl version: 

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check how Minikube is starting its Kubeapiserver: see "[Kubernetes PodPreset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783878/6309)".

You need to check "[Enable Pod Preset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/#enable-pod-preset)", especially:

> You have enabled the API type `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset`.
>   For example, this can be done by including `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true` in the `--runtime-config` option for the API server.

Comment: I believe that minikube has all apis by default.  See this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/316).

Comment: @RWood OK, there must be another requirement missing then.

Comment: @RWood: Have you found any solution to this problem? I'm facing this too.

Comment: Someone made a [suggestion](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2958#issuecomment-416160361) on the github issue that I created.  I didn't get the chance to try it out yet, so I don't know if it works